# How to tell if height of ListView items is bigger than heigh of actual ListView (i.e. can the list view be scrolled)?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've been searching around for an answer to this puzzle, but I can't seem to find anything definitive. Basically, is the height of the items (and dividers) in the ListView taller than the actual ListView itself, i.e. is there any list view items (or parts of items, or footer items) off the screen.

Somewhere inside the ListView must know if it can scroll (and how high) because it creates the scrollbars.

I've tried the `getMaxScrollAmount()` method (wrong), checking the `getLastVisiblePosition()` method (doesn't work if the last item is half showing), measuring the height of all the items from the adapter (performance fail, and wrong).

In iOS there's a very simple `contentSize` property of the UITableView with this answer, surely there's a simple solution.

Also, I want to know this *before* the user actually does any scrolling (but obviously after layout has happened).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does checking for `listView.canScrollList(-1) || listView.canScrollList(1)` work for you? It has the same mechanics as drawing the scrollbars.

[reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#canScrollList%28int%29)

Comment: This works, but appears to only be in Android 4.4. I also found `listView.canScrollVertically()` which seems to do what I want and is available since 4.0. I'm going to use this, but I'd still like a solution that works down to Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

After the list has calculated it's children view sizes (e.g. after layoutChildren()) you can test:

```
listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && listView.getLastVisiblePosition() < listView.getCount() - 1
```

Comment: That's basically the solution I ended up going with. The trick is calling that code at the right time in the drawing cycle.

Comment: Yes, it has to be after layout - e.g. I am extending ListView and use these methods on an overridden layoutChildren(), after calling super.layoutChildren();